# How to Define Layouts for Landscape Orientation in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do i define folder structure for layout resources in Android project, i know that there's generic folder structure like:

- layout
- layout-land
- layout-xhdpi
- layout-xxhdpi

But i wanna define separate landscape folders for my xhdpi and xxhdpi as well?

- layout-land-xhdpi
- layout-land-xxhdpi

I'm ubable to use layout-land-xhdpi for my landscape resources, moreover android studio preview is also not picking up layout resources from layout-land-xhdpi?

Comment: If your problem is with Android Studio and not on the device I suggest you update your question and tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the following qualifiers for xhdpi and xxhdpi devices and working fine for me, Secondly if android studio is not picking the right layouts in designer preview then try clearing the cache, cleaning the project or even restarting android studio will surely solves your problem.

> layout-land-xhdpi
>   layout-land-xxhdpi

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct qualifiers - it should be *large, xlarge, xlarge-land*, etc and NOT *XXHDPI*, etc:.

Here is the list of qualifiers ([from the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)) as they are designed to work:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density

res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

That doc is a MUST read for supporting multiple screens, I would review it (it will save you lots of time)

Comment: @Bogger i'm using density qualifiers, i-e xhdpi, xxhdpi, and secondly, i'm using layout-land-xxhdpi and android is picking it right from there i-e layout-land-xxhdpi, but i'm unable to preview it in visual designer of Android Studio

Comment: Well, I think you are NOT doing what the docs suggest, so it is expected you might have strange results.  I think you might be over complicating your design and should use the qualifiers described in the docs.  In my long Android history, I find doing thing per the suggested path makes things work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with the above answer.
Resources can be organized in various ways 
If you are using xlarge,xlarge-land etc you are organizing them according to screen size or screen resolution (WXGA etc)
But if you use xhdpi,xxhdpi etc you are organizing according to screen density.
So it is your wish how you want to organize your resources both are valid ways and have own use case scenario's.
If resources are not reflecting then either you are not using the device of that appropriate screen density (xxhdpi etc) while verifying or you have declared 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in your manifest which will disallow activity to use landscape mode layouts by calling onCreate() again.

Comment: @Ramesh it's working fine on my device i-e layouts are being picked from landscape orientation but i'm ubable to preview them on visual designer of AS